Symbol feels off-center in favicon
If you feel that this one is too nitty, please let me know and I'll close it.
It feels like the ₿ in the Favicon is closer to the right side of the speech bubble than the left. I'd assume that it's centered, but may appear off-center due to the slant?



disagree, can't see the misalignment

Now that you've pointed out, I can see it too. Moving it half a pixel to the left on the 32x32 favicon feels about right.

I'd agree, it looks slightly off-centre to the right to me as well
